# dotnet new not producing any output on my Mac

Tags: .net

I have scoured the net trying to figure out what is happening and how to fix it to no avail. I am trying to run the dotnet new command from the terminal. The command is found and seems to run, but produces no output in the directory. I am able to build and run apps and new lists templates, just doesn't product any output.

Is there any way to debug this? See some sort of diagnostic logging as to what it is doing and failing to do? I am guessing some sort of permission issue but I can't figure it out.

Comment: What does `dotnet --version` says?

Comment: The version is 2.1.402